# Is there way to get a consistent output from optFederov()?

Tags: programming

In R, when I create a full factorial plan with the `fac.design()` function from the DoE.base package to reduce the number of necessary runs, the `optFederov()` function from the AlgDesign package gives a different answer every time the code is executed.

What code should I add to ensure that the optFederov() function gives a consistent answer?

I tried to use `set.seed()` but it has no effect here.

Here is a dummy code to show you the problem:

```
library(DoE.base)
library(AlgDesign)
  
  plan <-
    fac.design(factor.names=list(A=c("A1","A2"),
                                 B=c("B1", "B2"),
                                 C=c("C1", "C2"),
                                 D=c("D1", "D2"),
                                 E=c("E1", "E2")),
               seed = 2000)
  
  
  optFederov(data = plan,
             nTrials = 16,
             approximate = FALSE)
```

Comment: Not strictly off topic, but https://stats.stackexchange.com might have better answers?

Comment: I tried there and they flagged my question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am late on the answer but this might help others. You need to use `set.seed()` before every call to `optFederov` in order to get consistent results.

For example, in the next code, design_1 and design_2 are different:

```
set.seed(42)
design_1 <- optFederov(data = plan,
                     nTrials = 16,
                     approximate = FALSE)

design_2 <- optFederov(data = plan,
                     nTrials = 16,
                     approximate = FALSE)

print(all(design_1$rows == design_2$rows))
#> FALSE
```

But if you use `set.seed` before each call to optFederov, you get consistent results:

```
set.seed(42)
design_3 <- optFederov(data = plan,
                     nTrials = 16,
                     approximate = FALSE)

set.seed(42)
design_4 <- optFederov(data = plan,
                     nTrials = 16,
                     approximate = FALSE)

print(all(design_3$rows == design_4$rows))
#> TRUE
```

You could also wrap optFederov in [a function that sets the seed locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324096/setting-seed-locally-not-globally-in-r) before calling it.

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution is simple and effective, but I would have never thought that the `set.seed()` function needed to be re-specified for each iteration of `optFederov()`. 

The work is going to become much easier :)